# Why doesn't grep using pipe work here?

Tags: shell, grep, pipe

I have the following command:

```
find / -name libGL.so.1
```

Which returns lots of lines with "Permission denied". I want to exclude such lines, so I added the following:

```
find / -name libGL.so.1 | grep -v 'denied'
```

But the output is the same - my `grep -v 'denied'` is not filtering out the lines with `Permission denied`. I've tried many variations, looked over grep tutorials, but I cannot figure out the problem. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

That's nothing to do with `grep` - it's because the pipe `|` redirects the standard output stream `stdout` whereas the `Permission denied` messages are in the standard error stream `stderr`. You could achieve the result you want by combining the streams using `2>&1` (redirect the stream whose file descriptor is `2` to the stream whose file descriptor is `1`) so that `stderr` as well as `stdout` gets piped to the input of the grep command

```
find / -name libGL.so.1 2>&1 | grep -v 'denied'
```

but it would be more usual to simply discard `stderr` altogether by redirecting it to `/dev/null`

```
find / -name libGL.so.1 2>/dev/null
```

#### Using |& instead of 2>&1 |

If you take a look at the Bash man page you'll likely notice this blurb:

> If `|&` is used,  the  standard error of command is connected to command2's standard input through the pipe; it is shorthand for `2>&1 |`.

So you can also use this construct as well if you want to join STDERR and STDOUT:

```
find / -name libGL.so.1 |& grep -v 'denied'
```

Comment: Additional note on combining them:  If for some bizarre reason the file exists at `/foo/bar/denied/libGL.so.1`, combining `stdout` and `stderr` _then_ filtering would hide the result

Answer (score 5):

Your command should be:

```
find / -name libGL.so.1 2>/dev/null
```

Find is complaining about permissions on standard error (fd2). In order to eliminate those lines, redirect (>) standard out to the bit bucket (/dev/null).

Answer (score 4):

The "permission denied" lines are going to the stderr (standard error) stream, but you are piping stdout (standard out) through grep.

You can redirect away stderr entirely with

```
find / -name libGL.so.1 2> /dev/null
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried calling the command with **sudo**?

```
sudo find / -name libGL.so.1
```

If it still shows the message, use the already mentioned redirect of *stderr (fd=2) to nirvana (/dev/null)*:

```
sudo find / -name libGL.so.1 2> /dev/null
```

More ideas [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/762348), good luck!