# How do you extract certain information from bzip2 -v?

Tags: text-processing, command-line, bzip2

Suppose I have a file called index.html and I want to compress it and display the compression size of it.  Well I would do this...

```
bzip2 index.html -v
```

Now that gives me all of the data bits/bytes, percent compression ratio, and the in and out compression.  Suppose I want the in number (in my case it is a 20).  Well this what I tried and it worked in other contexts with gzip I don't have a problem.

So normally I would use `awk` like so (but it doesn't work).

```
bzip2 index.html -v | awk '{print $4}'
```

I also tried

```
bzip2 index.html -v | cut -f4
```

The above attempts only produce whatever -v was giving me anyway and doesn't extract only the information that I want.  Here is an example output from my compressed index.html file

```
bzip2 index.html -v
index.html: 0.346:1, 22.00 bits/bytes, -175.00% saved, 20 in, 55 out
```

I'm trying to get the "20 in", more specifically just the number 20.

Comment: That would indicate the information is being printed to stderr. Try `|&` instead of `|`.

Comment: Likely the same reason as here: [Why doesn't grep using pipe work here?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128975/why-doesnt-grep-using-pipe-work-here)

Comment: Thanks, I would of never thought of that, I figured it would of been something simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bzip2` prints that information to stderr.   This prevents error messages from intermingling with decompressed data when one decompresses to stdout as with `bzip2 -dc` or `bzcat`.  You need to send stderr to awk.

My bzip2 produces this format

```
$ bzip2 index.html -v
  index.html:  1.444:1,  5.542 bits/byte, 30.73% saved, 179 in, 124 out.
```

To redirect stderr to stdout and use awk to select the compression number:

```
$ bzip2 index.html -v 2>&1 | awk '{print $5}'
30.73%
```

In shell, `0` is standard in, `1` is standard out, and `2` is standard error.  `2<&1` tells the shell to take standard error (`2`) and send it to standard out (`1`).

Comment: Thanks John1024, I don't normally deal with bash, so I appreciate it.